# How to find the parent node by matching text using XPath

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have some XML:

```
<sys>
  <lang>
    <employee>
      <name>Employee 1</name>
      <code>4fdaa994-7015-4ec1-b365-de4ee0279966</code>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Employee 2</name>
      <code>1d960bdc-0853-49af-bb83-18cf92493897</code>
    </employee>
</lang>
</syz>
```

How can I search and get the employee node where `name ="Employee 1"`?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
 obj.xpath("//sys/lang[/employee/name = 'Employee 1']")
```

Comment: Note end tag for `sys` is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath

```
/sys/lang/employee[name = 'Employee 1']
```

will select the `employee` element whose `name` is `Employee 1`.

---

**Why might OP be getting an "Invalid expression" using the above XPath?**

1. Transcription error.

   **Resolution**: Use copy and paste.
2. Single quotes around single quotes.

   **Resolution**: Use outer double quotes: `"/sys/lang/employee[name = 'Employee 1']"`
3. Smart quotes.

   **Resolution**: Replace `‘` and `’` with single quote `'`.
4. Misinterpretation of error message.

   **Resolution**: Carefully check any line number mentioned in error, or carve away surrounding code as much as possible, and see if error goes away.

If none of the above possibilities apply, post a MCVE ([**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including the provided XPath *and* the calling code -- the ***complete*** in MCVE) that produces the invalid expression error, and someone will likely immediately spot the problem.

Comment: its giving me invalid expression

Comment: Then you've made a mistake in applying it to your code, because the XPath is most definitely valid and correct.

Comment: i have tried a lot but its not working, it gives me invalid expression error. could it be version related?

Comment: **Edit your question and add your *exact* code and the *exact* error message.**  With just a little bit of effort on your part, it will be trivial for us to show you exactly where your mistake is.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello kjhuges, this is the exact code i have and the error is see is "Invalid expression" and i am upvoting your answer but its bot working as a solution for my problem

Comment: @opensource-ios: Answer updated with possible causes of "invalid expression".  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @kjhughes, i will check and update you soon on the findings.

Comment: Hello @kjhughes, accepting your answer, thanks for your help and descriptive answer. I am sure it will help many

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using CSS over XPath for readability reasons. Nokogiri implements a number of jQuery's extensions to make it easier to use CSS for things we'd usually use XPath for.

I'd do it this way:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<sys>
  <lang>
    <employee>
      <name>Employee 1</name>
      <code>4fdaa994-7015-4ec1-b365-de4ee0279966</code>
    </employee>
    <employee>
      <name>Employee 2</name>
      <code>1d960bdc-0853-49af-bb83-18cf92493897</code>
    </employee>
</lang>
</syz>
EOT

emp1 = doc.at('employee name:contains("Employee 1")') # => #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ffed05285b4 name="name" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3ffed05283d4 "Employee 1">]>
emp1.to_xml # => "<name>Employee 1</name>"
emp1.parent.to_xml # => "<employee>\n      <name>Employee 1</name>\n      <code>4fdaa994-7015-4ec1-b365-de4ee0279966</code>\n    </employee>"
```

Also note, it's not good practice to define the full path in the selector for a node. If the HTML or XML changes the structure that selector will break. Instead, find useful landmarks and hop from one to the next. That way your selector is more likely to survive changes in the markup. I only care about finding the appropriate `<employee>...<name>` combination, not those two tags embedded under `<sys>` and `<lang>`.

Sometimes an alternate way of getting to the information you want is to use `search` and look at a particular index:

```
doc.search('employee').first.to_xml # => "<employee>\n      <name>Employee 1</name>\n      <code>4fdaa994-7015-4ec1-b365-de4ee0279966</code>\n    </employee>"
```

Or:

```
doc.at('employee').to_xml           # => "<employee>\n      <name>Employee 1</name>\n      <code>4fdaa994-7015-4ec1-b365-de4ee0279966</code>\n    </employee>"
```

`at('some selector')` is equivalent to `search('some selector').first`.